# Problem with converting array to json in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this code:

```
var fields = [];
$('input').each(function(){
  var name = $(this).attr("name");
  fields[name] = $(name).val();
});
```

And I want convert the `fields` variable to a json string, but when I use `JSON.stringify` I get (using `console.log`) only: `[]`

How can I simply convert array `fields` to a json string?

Answer (score 2):

Ok problem was on the following line:

```
 fields[name] = $(name).val();
```

I changed `name` to `this`:

```
 fields[name] = $(this).val();
```

And worked like i want it to.

Answer (score 1):

If you want text strings like field names (as opposed to numbers) as property names, you want an *object*, not an array. Initialize `fields` to `{}` instead of `[]`.

The JSON serialization of an array will only include the properties whose keys are numbers, from zero up to the value of `.length` (minus one).

Comment: When i initialize `fieldes` as `{}` using `console.log` i got `{}`

Comment: @jacewojtek then you don't have any inputs on the page.

Comment: @jacewojtek if your code is placed in a `<script>` at the **top** of the page, then it runs before the DOM is constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Just made one correction, use object instead of array:

```
    var fields = {};
    $('input').each(function(){
     var name = $(this).attr("name");
     fields[name] = $(name).val();
    });
```